# flutter type error future <dynamic> is not a subtype of type future <bool>

Tags: flutter, dart

So i'm trying to stop the sound that is playing when i leave the Hero widget but the _stop() method is causing the exception in the title

```
Future _stop() async{
    var result = await flutterTts.stop();
    if (result == 1) setState(() => ttsState = TtsState.stopped);
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
        child: Scaffold(),
        onWillPop: (){
            return _stop();
        },
    );
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onWillPop` property takes a `Future` of type `bool`. try returning a `bool` at end of your `_stop` function:

```dart
Future<bool> _stop() async{
var result = await flutterTts.stop();
if (result == 1) setState(() => ttsState = TtsState.stopped);
return true; // returning bool
}
```